# Как заполнить ListView с помощью EditText?

Tags: android, listview

Добрый день.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как заполнить ListView c помощью Диалогового Окна (C EditText)?
Мне надо Заполнить Список по именам, для этого взял EditText, для более презентабельного вида поместил его в AlertDialog, но никак не получается получить из него данные и заполнить ими ListView.
P.S. опыта от силы неделя, так что не судите строго за корявый код

```
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add);
        players = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        final ListView plist =(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listplayers);

        final ArrayList<String> playnames = new ArrayList<String>();
//
        final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.item, (List<String>) plist);
        plist.setAdapter(adapter);



        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
                View dialogView = li.inflate(R.layout.dialog, null);

                AlertDialog.Builder mDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

                mDialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);

                final EditText login = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.Login);

                mDialogBuilder.setTitle("Введите имя");
                mDialogBuilder.setCancelable(true);
                mDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Далее", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
//                                players.setText(login.getText());
                       ((List<String>) plist).add(0,login.getText().toString());
                    }
                });
                mDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Отмена", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        dialogInterface.cancel();
                    }
                });
                AlertDialog alertDialog = mDialogBuilder.create();

                alertDialog.show();

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: готов помочь, установи теамвивер и напиши на почту martsinkevych@mail.ru. За компютером буду минут через 30-40